# Java error applying poll() to a LinkedList

Tags: java, list, linked-list

If I try this:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1));
int val = list.poll();
```

I get:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    int val = list.poll();
                  ^
  symbol:   method poll()
  location: variable list of type List<Integer>
```

I am not understanding why. Should `val` not be `1`? I have imported all the necessary libraries

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), there function `poll` is listed and the documentation says:
*Retrieves and removes the head (first) of this list.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
List<Integer> list
```

List class does not have poll method, it's part of Deque and Deque interface which LinkedList implements. In documentation you have information from which class/interface the method was first specified by looking at '**Specified by:**' section.

Comment: so how do I know from the documentation if a method matches with that data type? 
Is there an alternative method for poll() I can apply to List<Integer> ?

Comment: In same documentation you have information if the method is from other interface. There is information just below description in case of poll method: "Specified by: poll in interface Deque<E>", there is also other "Specified by" which points to Queue<E> interface. The alternative for poll() for List is simply get(0) then remove(0)